# Error on executing localstack init script file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, localstack

I use example from localstack docs:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "/path/to/init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"  # ready hook
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I try the same, but I got error.
My code here:

```
  localstack_proj:
    container_name: localstack_proj
    image: localstack/localstack:2.3
    hostname: localstack_proj
    env_file:
      - innotter/.env
    ports:
      - "4567:4566"
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOSTNAME=localstack_proj
    networks:
      - ntwk
    volumes:
      - "./init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"
      - localstack-data:/tmp/localstack
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR --- [  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh'
```

I don't know how I can give permissions to that file.